# Motherboard has one HDMI port but supports three monitors. How can it?

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi

I am looking at an [Asus motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87MPLUS/specifications/) and it says :

```
Integrated Graphics Processor 
Multi-VGA output support : HDMI/DVI-D/RGB ports 
 - Supports HDMI with max. resolution 4096 x 2160 @ 24 Hz / 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
 - Supports DVI-D with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
 - Supports RGB with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
Maximum shared memory of 1024 MB
Supports Intel® InTru™ 3D, Quick Sync Video, Clear Video HD Technology, Insider™
Supports up to 3 displays simultaneously
```

Having read the manual it's not clear if the three monitors it supports are {1 HDMI + 1 DVI-D and 1 RGB} or {3 HDMI covering the 4096*2160 area}.

I'd ideally like to support three HDMI monitors (without buying a graphics card), ie, to get the 4096 * 2160 split over two or three monitors with HDMI .

I'm noting looking to do any gaming, I just want a really good home set up for web dev and general computing.  As I'm not going to be gaming I'd rather not get a separate graphics card.

Am I unaware of an obvious trick to support three monitors from a single port?  Or do I have to get a graphics card to support multiple monitors via the same interface? Or (given that I have only one monitor at present) aim to get the subsequent ones over different interfaces? Although I have read that [using a VGA port with a modern monitor is a waste of time](https://superuser.com/a/407152/325591).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Multi-VGA output support : HDMI/DVI-D/RGB ports 
 - Supports HDMI with max. resolution 4096 x 2160 @ 24 Hz / 2560 x 1600 @ 60 Hz
 - Supports DVI-D with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
 - Supports RGB with max. resolution 1920 x 1200 @ 60 Hz
Maximum shared memory of 1024 MB
Supports Intel® InTru™ 3D, Quick Sync Video, Clear Video HD Technology, Insider™
Supports up to 3 displays simultaneously`

Based on this information, yes it can support 3 monitors, 1 connection from the HDMI, 1 from the DVI-D and 1 from the VGA Port.

[image]

Not all from 1 hdmi connection. And if using a VGA is a problem, get a VGA to DVI converter.

[image]

edit: if you really want a full DVI/HDMI with upto 4 monitors I'd recommend looking into higher end stand alone video cards that normally support 2 dvi, 1 hdmi, and 1 display port. Or other combinations that don't include VGA.

Comment: That VGA to DVI converter will only work if your monitor supports DVI-A.  It will not work for all DVI monitors.

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought I had once seen a cable which split a single HDMI (or DVI) into two, so that a single port powered two monitors, and wondered if I had to find a three way splitter but what you've both said makes sense.